# failed to map segment from shared object hazelcast mancenter

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I have Hazelcast 4.2 runs in a linux server in a standalone mode by running the following files in background:

hazelcast management center : management-center/bin/start.sh

but hazelcast management center is not starting properly.

error while start up;-

lization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mapManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/hazelcast-4.2/management-center/hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.03.jar!/com/hazelcast/webmonitor/service/MapManager.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clientNearCacheStatsManager' defined in URL [jar:file:hazelcast-4.2/management-center/hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.03.jar!/com/hazelcast/webmonitor/service/ClientNearCacheStatsManager.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'metricsService' defined in URL [jar:file:hazelcast-4.2/management-center/hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.03.jar!/com/hazelcast/webmonitor/service/metrics/MetricsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metricsStorage' defined in class path resource [com/hazelcast/webmonitor/config/MetricsStorageConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.webmonitor.metrics.MetricsStorage]: Factory method 'metricsStorage' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/librocksdbjni6522772346884591428.so: /tmp/librocksdbjni6522772346884591428.so: failed to map segment from shared object
2021-04-05 09:52:01,221 [ERROR] [main] [o.s.w.c.ContextLoader]: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mapManager' defined in URL [jar:file:

browser:-
HTTP ERROR 503 Service Unavailable
URI:    /
STATUS: 503
MESSAGE:    Service Unavailable
SERVLET:    -

how to fix this issue ? how to start hazelcast idmg

Answer (score 0):

please try to remount your /tmp dir

```
sudo mount /tmp -o remount,exec
```